# Linq fast intersect query - enhancement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, plinq

In our company there are thousands(!) of cars. each car has a GPS device which sends periodically (`cycle`) its location.

So each `Cycle` contains :

- `List<Cars>` ( cars that sent location – corresponding to the `CycleNum`)
- `CycleNum` which is Cycle number

`CycleNum` is determined by *a server*.

So for example in `CycleNum=1`  , 4 cars sent their location :

[image]

Classes I used ( simplification )

```
static int TotalCycles=0;

class Car
{
 public int CarId;
 public int Location ;
}


class Cycle
{
  public  int CycleNum;
  public List<Car> Cars;
  public Cycle ()
    {
      CycleNum=(++TotalCycles);
    }
     
}
```

Let's fill some data :

```
   List<Cycle> LstCyclces = new List<Cycle>();
   Cycle cycle =null;

   cycle = new Cycle();//cycle 1
   cycle.Cars = new List<Car>();
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=1 , Location=40});
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=2 , Location=21});
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=3 , Location=5});
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=4 , Location=15});
   LstCyclces.Add(cycle);
   
   cycle = new Cycle();//cycle2
   cycle.Cars = new List<Car>();
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=1 , Location=40}); //same location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=2 , Location=57});//changed location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=3 , Location=100});//changed location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=4 , Location=7});//changed location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=7 , Location=2});//new attended ( vs previous cycle)
   LstCyclces.Add(cycle);
   
   cycle = new Cycle();//cycle3
   cycle.Cars = new List<Car>();
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=1 , Location=40}); //same
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=2 , Location=5});//changed Location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=4 , Location=1});//changed Location
   cycle.Cars.Add(new Car {CarId=9 , Location=7});//new attended ( vs previous cycle)
   LstCyclces.Add(cycle);
```

Visualization :

[image]

As you can see :

- A new car can come in to the cycle
- A car can also get out from a cycle
- A car can change Location(obviously)

**Question**

I was asked  to:

For a specific given cycle Number — find all Cars that were also anticipated in the *previous cycle* where :

`("new Location" - "previous Location") < abs(40)`

And from *that result set* ,  find all cars PAIRS where :

`(Car_A.Location - Car_B.Location) < abs(65)`

In short - I need all cars that gave me info also for the previous cycle and also they didn't go very far from their previous location and finally  - from those cars -  I need to know which cars are near to each other.

*Very important :  I can not check only current Location , because we need to make sure also that cars didn't get very far from their previous location.*

So according to the picture : looking at `cycleNum=2` :

The cars who anticipated also in the previous Cycle (1)  were  Cars:  1,2,3,4.

From that result : The cars who didn't go very far from their previous location :

`("new Location" - "previous Location") < abs(40)`

Were cars : 1,2,4.

From that result I need to find all pairs of car who are now not far from each other :

`(Car_A.Location - Car_B.Location) < abs(65)` :

So the result should be IEnumerable: (format isn't matter )

- `{ Car1 ,  Car2 , distance=17}` //the distance between those 2 cars  < 65
- `{ Car1 ,  Car4 , distance=33}` //the distance between those 2 cars  < 65
- `{ Car2 ,  Car4 , distance=50}` //the distance between those 2 cars  < 65

//I dont mind having all permutation `( {car1 car2} , {car2 car1} )`

What have I tried :

```
   var cycleToCheck=2;
   //get all cars from desired cycle
   var requestedCycleCars =  LstCyclces.Where(c=>c.CycleNum==cycleToCheck).SelectMany(c=>c.Cars);
   //get all cars from previous  cycle
   var previousCycleCars =  LstCyclces.Where(c=>c.CycleNum==cycleToCheck-1).SelectMany(c=>c.Cars);
   //intersec between those 
   var MyWrongIntersect =requestedCycleCars.Intersect(previousCycleCars,new MyEqualityComparer());
```

But I only  get cars from the current cycle and not from previous cycle ,Also - I need reference both to cars from current cycle and previous cycle(*without reiterating*) - for calculations.

Also I think I'm on the wrong path using `SelectMany` and this is suppose to be the fastest it can be(c# , plinq?). I wish it could be in one query.

Any help ?

## [Full code working online](http://ideone.com/hbX0sV)

nb , of course I can do it in phases , but reiterating , or ToList()'s are bad approach for me. I was hoping for a single plinq query

## Edit

Posted solution works OK logically but not performantly.

2 cycles , where each has 10,000 cars  : > 9min!!! :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjLvG.jpg

[image]

**How can I improve it?** (asparallel didnt work much)

Comment: Have you considered sorting? A simple sort could reduce the number of actual comparisons you actually have to make. At present (without really thinking about it) I believe your algorithm has `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Aron are you are talking about the `&& x.Item1.CarId < x.Item2.CarId` part ?

Comment: Nope I meant the `(Car_A.Location - Car_B.Location) < abs(65)` part. If you sort the cars by location, then obviously the first car and the last car is not going to be in a similar location. Try to store your data in a form that make querying quick. That the basis of databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as far as the efficiency goes,

`From that result I need to find all pairs of car who are now not far from each other :` is the one that is pretty killer for performance, assuming that there are a lot of such pairs. The naive algorithm would run `n^2` atleast. You'd want to use SQL spatial type, which would make the query a lot more efficient.

If you are not willing to do it/can't, there's not much you can do to improve the performance, I am willing to guess.

Here is a next code that will do efficient join between `Cars`. It's important that `CarId` is indexed. After we have find all the pairs `c.Distance <40`, we'll do the final processing on client's computer, as this allows us to process the sorted cars by ourselves in an efficient manner.

```
var cycleNum = 2;

var curCycleCars = LstCyclces[cycleNum - 1].Cars;
var prevCycleCars = LstCyclces[cycleNum - 2].Cars;

var cars = curCycleCars.Join(prevCycleCars, 
                    p => p.CarId, 
                    y => y.CarId,
                    (f1, f2) => new { 
                            Car = f1,
                            Distance = f1.Location - f2.Location
                        })
                    .Where(c => c.Distance < 40)
                    .Select(c => c.Car)
                    .OrderBy(car => car.Location)
                    .ToList();



var carPairs = new CarPairList[cars.Count()];

for(var i = 0; i < cars.Count; i++)
{
    var curCar = cars[i];
    var curStartIndex = i + 1;

    if(i > 0)
    {
        var previousCarPair = carPairs[i - 1];
        if(previousCarPair!=null)
        {
            curStartIndex = previousCarPair.EndIndex;
        }
    }

    int j;
    for(j = curStartIndex; j < cars.Count; j++)
    {
        var dis = cars[j].Location - curCar.Location;
        if(dis >= 65) break;
    }

    var startIndex = i + 1;
    var endIndex = j - 1;

    if(endIndex >= startIndex)
    {
        carPairs[i] = new CarPairList(curCar, 
                            startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}

foreach(var carPair in carPairs.Where(x => x!=null)){
    Console.WriteLine("Car " + carPair.Car.CarId);
    Console.WriteLine("Cars near the distance: ");

    for(var i = carPair.StartIndex; i <= carPair.EndIndex; i++){
        Console.WriteLine("\t - {0}, distance {1}", 
            cars[i].CarId,
            cars[i].Location - carPair.Car.Location);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

class CarPairList
{
    public readonly Car Car;
    public readonly int StartIndex;
    public readonly int EndIndex;

    public CarPairList(Car car, 
        int startIndex,
        int endIndex){
        Car = car;
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        EndIndex = endIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: NO sql . all in memory processing :-) ( and we have alot)

Comment: it's weird thought that non of the answers uses plinq  to make max cores hot?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, there's not much to parallelize imo. The data is dependent. You can try adding `.AsParallel()` before ToList(). Btw I also changed the way how car pairs are found. The memory allocation is now minimum, and it should be a lot faster.

Comment: & also, without the PRINTING part, the above algorithm should take 1 second maximum with ~10 000 cars, as the running time is O(nlogn). If it takes more than that, you're going wrong somewhere else.

Comment: im just trying it (pasting to vs)

Comment: 100% ( 1M cars , less than 2 sec) , you're great

Answer (score 2):

Tty this code

```
    var cycleToCheck = 2;

    var query = LstCyclces.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CycleNum == cycleToCheck).Cars
                                .Where(c => LstCyclces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CycleNum == cycleToCheck - 1).Cars
                                            .Any(ca => ca.CarId == c.CarId && Math.Abs(c.Location - ca.Location) < 40));

    var result = query.SelectMany(t1 => query.Select(t2 => Tuple.Create(t1, t2)))
            .Where(x => Math.Abs(x.Item1.Location - x.Item2.Location) < 65 && x.Item1.CarId < x.Item2.CarId);


    foreach (var r in result)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", r.Item1.CarId, r.Item2.CarId);
    }
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bTHIYW) is working sample

**Edited**

Comment: +1 Thank you. However I'm trying to avoid(as i said) Tolists() and middle buffers , and hopefully using plinq , since I told , we have thousands(!) of cars ( and this is very simplified code that I gave , the actually class are a bit bigger).

Comment: The `query.SelectMany(t1 => query.Select(t2 => Tuple.Create(t1, t2)));` is geniously. im still thinking how it works. ( combination generator)

Comment: It's actually transformed to `CROSS JOIN` in `SQL`

Comment: Can you please see my edit ? about execution times ?

Comment: @MaxBrodin Is there a reason you use Tuple.Create instead of `new { MeaningfulPropertyName = t1, OtherMeaningfulPropertyName = t2 }` ?

Comment: After you found cars for the `cycleToCheck` you have a `Where` call that calls `LstCyclces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CycleNum == cycleToCheck - 1)` for every car which is not efficient. You can calculate in once.

Comment: @takemyoxygen I dont understand . this condition is mandatory for the first query.can you please post the suggested fix ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, sorry, it was a fix for @MaxBrodin answer. He could calculate this `LstCyclces.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CycleNum == cycleToCheck - 1)` once and store in variable instead of calculating it on every iteration in the `Where` clause

Comment: @takemyoxygen but it DOES needs to find out for each(!) car if it was in the previous cycle. or are you talking about the scalar value ?